# Fitting a negative binomial model and covariance structure syntax in glmmTMB

Tags: r, longitudinal, covariance-matrix, glmmtmb

I read the glmmTMB package vignettes (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/covstruct.html) and have the following questions:

1. In the vignetts, they fit the model using

```
glmmTMB(y~ar1(times+0|group),data=dat0)
```

and mentioned that the `time+0` correspondes to a design matrix Z linking observation vector y (rows) with a random effects vector u(columns)"

What's the meaning of `+0`? Is there any difference with `(times|group)`, `(times+1|group)` and `(1|group)`?

Are there any comprehensive summary about the syntax of the covariance structure?

2. If I want to fit a Negtive binomial model when outcome y_{ij} is generated from R function: `rnbinom(mu=x_{ij}beta+b_i+e_{ij},size=1)`, where i is the group index and j is the individual index, and b_i～N(0,1), e_{ij}~N(0,1). Would the following code correctly specify to model?

```
dat <- data.frame(y,x,group)
glmmTMB(y~x+(1|group),data=dat,family=nbinom2)
```

Any suggestion and help is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!